# angular 2 with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am a rails dev and newbie to angular.

I am working on angular as front-end and rails as backend.

Same as rails, I want to redirect to a show page after record is created.

Below is my code (bm-biller-add.component.ts) :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BmBiller } from '../bm_biller';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bm-biller-add',
  templateUrl: './bm-biller-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bm-biller-add.component.css']
})

export class BmBillerAddComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService, public acRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }

  public bm_biller : BmBiller = new BmBiller();

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    this.apiService.post("bm_billers", this.bm_biller).subscribe((r)=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/bm_billers/',r.id]);
    });
  }

}
```

When the angular app starts, it throws an err :-

```
ERROR in src/app/bm-biller-add/bm-biller-add.component.ts(25,46): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Which is the err in this line :-

```
this.router.navigate(['/bm_billers/',r.id]);
```

Am I doing it right way? 
I have tried checking is r (response) != undefined, still it throws an err.

Comment: Change `subscribe((r)=>{` to `subscribe((r: any)=>{` which will tell the compiler that `r` can have any properties

Comment: the issue is fixed after changing to r: any. 

thanks user184994